# convert a javascript code snippet to php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript code like this.I want to convert this code in to php.As am a beginer in PHP am struggling to convert this code snippet in to PHP.How can i perform this?

java script

```
 var view = [{data: [["1:24:22", 969],["1:24:42", 970],["1:25:03", 972]]}, {data: [["2:35:22", 969],["2:44:42", 970],["2:55:03", 972]]}];
    view.forEach(function (r) {
        k = 0;
        r.data.forEach(function (d) {
            d[0] = ++k;
        });
    });

i tried
```

php

```
$view = [{data: [["1:24:22", 969],["1:24:42", 970],["1:25:03", 972]]}, {data: [["2:35:22", 969],["2:44:42", 970],["2:55:03", 972]]}];
```

Comment: your 'php' has syntax error

Comment: Please show evidence of at least making an attempt to understand the equivalent PHP syntax. We aren't a code conversion service.

Comment: PHP does not have object literals like JavaScript. What it does have is associative arrays which behave practically the same but only use the square-bracket syntax and `=>` instead of `:`, eg `$view = [['data' => ...`

Comment: How are you trying to modify the time exactly?

Comment: Google 'php arrays' and 'php associative arrays'... some javascript code like this doesn't translate well to PHP since PHP is procedural/object-oriented and javascript is prototypical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is PHP version of your javascript. `$view` is taken as JSON string and it can be manipulated as below. I appreciate @Marty's comment, but I think to help you.

```
$view = '[{"data": [["1:24:22", "969"],["1:24:42", "970"],["1:25:03", "972"]]}, {"data": [["2:35:22", "969"],["2:44:42", "970"],["2:55:03", "972"]]}]';
$view = json_decode($view);
foreach($view as $r){
    $k=0;
    foreach($r->data as $d){
        $d[0] = ++$k;
    }
}
```